# Splitting a main window into 2 using frames

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[Updated Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htMEG.png)I am designing a GUI and I want to split the main window into 2 separate windows using frames just like how it is in an IDE.
Here is what I have tried till now

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Text-Editor')
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
root.geometry("1400x660")
root.columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)

my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
my_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
my_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
my_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

left_frame = Frame(my_frame)
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
left_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
left_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_frame = Frame(my_frame)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")
right_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

scrollbar_object = Scrollbar(left_frame)
scrollbar_object2 = Scrollbar(right_frame)
scrollbar_object.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
scrollbar_object2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)[Scrollbar image][2]
```

In the code above I am able to see 2 frames left and right with scrollbars but they are completely covering the entire window . How do I cover the entire window I have included the image as to how I am getting it. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF2Yj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first remark: the first line "import tkinter as Tk" is not really usefull because you also write "from tkinter import *". Although I usually prefer using "import tkinter as tk" I left the line "from tkinter import *".

To answer your question:
You where on the right track using the columnconfigure. But in order to make it work, basically everywhere you specified a "sticky=nswe" you have to make sure that the container of this widget has its row configured to have a specific weight, and its column configured to have a specific weight.

Keep also in mind that the weight only specifies the distribution of the space it has to much, and not all the space itself.

Here is what works, you can try and comment different lines out to see the effect on the widget:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import subprocess
import os
from tkinter import *

my_window = Tk()
my_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
my_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

main_frame = Frame(my_window)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


left_frame = Frame(main_frame)
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
right_frame = Frame(main_frame)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")

left_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
right_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


listbox_object = Listbox(right_frame)
listbox_object2 = Listbox(right_frame)
listbox_object.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
listbox_object2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nswe")

scrollbar_object = Scrollbar(right_frame)
scrollbar_object2 = Scrollbar(right_frame)
scrollbar_object.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
scrollbar_object2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='ns')


my_window.mainloop()
```

What you want:

```
from tkinter import *

my_window = Tk()
my_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
my_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

main_frame = Frame(my_window)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

left_frame = Frame(main_frame)
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
left_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
left_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_frame = Frame(main_frame)
right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")
right_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
right_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
listbox_object = Listbox(left_frame)
listbox_object2 = Listbox(right_frame)
listbox_object.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
listbox_object2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

scrollbar_object = Scrollbar(left_frame)
scrollbar_object2 = Scrollbar(right_frame)
scrollbar_object.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
scrollbar_object2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: i got it and it is doing most of the work that i want. But there is still empty space on the left. How do i fill up that space is my question.i have also updated the image as to how it is looking right now.

Comment: The empty space on the left is the left_frame. What you did was fill your main frame with a left frame and a right frame, and fill the right frame with 2 listboxes and 2 scrollbars. If you want the entire space to be covered with just the two listboxes, you don't need the left frame, and you can directly put everything in the main frame.
(I also put a new version in the answer)

Comment: I want the entire space to be filled up with left frame and right frame. However in the image the left_frame is not completely covering the space like how the right frame is completely covering the space. I want my left side of the window to look as the same as my right side

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want, but I have made a new edit with what I think is what you expect.

Comment: Yeah Thank You , this is what i wanted

Comment: if i have to split the left frame as 25% and right frame as 75%. How do i assign the weights accordingly?

Comment: as in i want the 25% of the entire space to be occupied by the left frame and rest 75% by the right frame

Comment: You can change the 10th line to "main_frame.columnconfigure(1, 3)". That way the right frame will get 3 times more of the EXESS width than the left frame. If you want the right frame to be absolutely 3 times as wide you can specify a width for the listbox_objects. (for ex. "listbox_object = Listbox(left_frame, width=20)" and with width=60 for the right listbox. That way the right one will start with being 3 times as wide and will get also 75% of all the extra width when resizing.

Comment: Okay will try that let u knos

Comment: i have 1 more doubt. i have edited my code and added an image as scrollbar image. The issue is the entire scrollbar isnt visible and only as part of it is visible.Can you let me know what the mistake is?

Comment: how do i make both the scrollbars on the left and right frame to work?